# Data structure/Container choice

Tags: c++, qt, collections

I have the following scenario:

- Data from multiple video files needs to be held in a data structure/collection.
- A video file can have 1 to many video streams.
- Each stream has a field and value pair.

For example:

```
Video1:
  Stream1:
    format mpeg
    bitrate 700kb/s
    resolution 1024x764

  Stream2:
    format mpeg
    bitrate 600kb/s
    resolution 800x600

Video2:
  Stream1:
    format mpeg
    bitrate 700kb/s
    resolution 1024x764

  Stream2:
    format mpeg
    bitrate 600kb/s
    resolution 800x600
```

This is what I was consider holding the data in:

```
QVector<QVector<QStringList>>
```

Where `QStringList` are the value pairs (format, mpeg).

Inside `QVector` holds the multiple pairs for the stream.

Outside `QVector` holds the everything i.e. each entry/index is data for a single video file.

I'm not sure whether this is the best way to hold the data a I guess a collection inside a collection inside a collection is not going to be very efficient.

Any opinions on alternatives?

Comment: Quit tagging your titles please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not write classes as you need?

```
class Stream
{
    Format format;
    Resolution res;
    Bitrate br;
};

class Video
{
    QVector<Stream> v_stream;
};

class VideoContainer
{
    QVector<Video> v_video;
};
```

Comment: Is there some performance lost using custom classes within a collection?

Comment: @johnnyturbo3: no. everything will be ultimately converted to some kind of integer manipulation. but you can always benchmark your program.

Comment: If you have fixed set of attributes custom class as Stream will be even faster then all other variants. If you have dynamic set of attributes, you'd better use QMap.

Answer (score 2):

QVector required to continuous location of data such as classical C-array. For general purposes recommended QList instead of QVector  which also provides fast index-based access but based on pointers.

Answer (score 1):

For field-value pairs use QMap instead of StringList, thst would be easier to access. Maybe even `QMap<QString,QVariant>` or `QMap<QString,QString>` if you use only text properties.

Also, as triclosan said, use `QList` instead of `QVector`. So final look would be `QList<QList<QMap< QString,QVariant > > >`